# Joomla / Google Embed API

Tags: javascript, joomla, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, joomla3.0

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to embed the Google Analytics Embed API in my custom Joomla! component:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations

I'm not a javascript guy, but it seems like (from the console error) that it's not loading the different scripts in order, but I'm using 'defer' in my script reference so I don't think that's really the issue.

**Console Error Message:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ActiveUsers' of undefined
(anonymous function) @ index.php?option=com_site&view=tools&page=analytics:138
yv @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:729
(anonymous function) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:730
(anonymous function) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:704
f @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:699
h.r2 @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:79
xs @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:82
Wq @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:82
_.C.uea @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:81
Ap @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:75
```

**My component view code:**

```
<?php


// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();


JHTML::stylesheet("com_supersite/chartjs-visualizations.css", array(), true);

JHTML::script("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js");
JHTML::script("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js");

$doc->addScript(JURI::root() . 'media/com_site/js/embed-api/view-selector2.js', "text/javascript", true, false);
$doc->addScript(JURI::root() . 'media/com_site/js/embed-api/date-range-selector.js', "text/javascript", true, false);
$doc->addScript(JURI::root() . 'media/com_site/js/embed-api/active-users.js', "text/javascript", true, false);

$js = <<<JS
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));


gapi.analytics.ready(function() {


  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'myfakeid.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  });

  /**
   * Create a new ActiveUsers instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "active-users-container" and poll for changes every
   * five seconds.
   */
  var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
    container: 'active-users-container',
    pollingInterval: 5
  });


  /**
   * Add CSS animation to visually show the when users come and go.
   */
  activeUsers.once('success', function() {
    var element = this.container.firstChild;
    var timeout;

    this.on('change', function(data) {
      var element = this.container.firstChild;
      var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
      element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        element.className =
            element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
      }, 3000);
    });
  });


  /**
   * Create a new ViewSelector2 instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "view-selector-container".
   */
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
    container: 'view-selector-container',
  })
  .execute();


  /**
   * Update the activeUsers component, the Chartjs charts, and the dashboard
   * title whenever the user changes the view.
   */
  viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
    var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
    title.textContent = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';

    // Start tracking active users for this view.
    activeUsers.set(data).execute();

    // Render all the of charts for this view.
    renderWeekOverWeekChart(data.ids);
    renderYearOverYearChart(data.ids);
    renderTopBrowsersChart(data.ids);
    renderTopCountriesChart(data.ids);
  });


  /**
   * Draw the a chart.js line chart with data from the specified view that
   * overlays session data for the current week over session data for the
   * previous week.
   */
  function renderWeekOverWeekChart(ids) {

    // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
    var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

    var thisWeek = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    var lastWeek = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).subtract(1, 'week')
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(6).subtract(1, 'week')
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    Promise.all([thisWeek, lastWeek]).then(function(results) {

      var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var labels = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[0]; });

      labels = labels.map(function(label) {
        return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('ddd');
      });

      var data = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Last Week',
            fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
            strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            pointColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
            data : data2
          },
          {
            label: 'This Week',
            fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
            pointColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
            pointStrokeColor : '#fff',
            data : data1
          }
        ]
      };

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-1-container')).Line(data);
      generateLegend('legend-1-container', data.datasets);
    });
  }


  /**
   * Draw the a chart.js bar chart with data from the specified view that
   * overlays session data for the current year over session data for the
   * previous year, grouped by month.
   */
  function renderYearOverYearChart(ids) {

    // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
    var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

    var thisYear = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
      'metrics': 'ga:users',
      'start-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    var lastYear = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
      'metrics': 'ga:users',
      'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'year').date(1).month(0)
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).subtract(1, 'day')
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    Promise.all([thisYear, lastYear]).then(function(results) {
      var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                    'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

      // Ensure the data arrays are at least as long as the labels array.
      // Chart.js bar charts don't (yet) accept sparse datasets.
      for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (data1[i] === undefined) data1[i] = null;
        if (data2[i] === undefined) data2[i] = null;
      }

      var data = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Last Year',
            fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
            strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            data : data2
          },
          {
            label: 'This Year',
            fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            strokeColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
            data : data1
          }
        ]
      };

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-2-container')).Bar(data);
      generateLegend('legend-2-container', data.datasets);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
    });
  }


  /**
   * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
   * show the top 5 browsers over the past seven days.
   */
  function renderTopBrowsersChart(ids) {

    query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
      'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
      'max-results': 5
    })
    .then(function(response) {

      var data = [];
      var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

      response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
        data.push({ value: +row[1], color: colors[i], label: row[0] });
      });

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-3-container')).Doughnut(data);
      generateLegend('legend-3-container', data);
    });
  }


  /**
   * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
   * compares sessions from mobile, desktop, and tablet over the past seven
   * days.
   */
  function renderTopCountriesChart(ids) {
    query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:country',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'sort': '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': 5
    })
    .then(function(response) {

      var data = [];
      var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

      response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
        data.push({
          label: row[0],
          value: +row[1],
          color: colors[i]
        });
      });

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-4-container')).Doughnut(data);
      generateLegend('legend-4-container', data);
    });
  }


  /**
   * Extend the Embed APIs `gapi.analytics.report.Data` component to
   * return a promise the is fulfilled with the value returned by the API.
   * @param {Object} params The request parameters.
   * @return {Promise} A promise.
   */
  function query(params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
      data.once('success', function(response) { resolve(response); })
          .once('error', function(response) { reject(response); })
          .execute();
    });
  }


  /**
   * Create a new canvas inside the specified element. Set it to be the width
   * and height of its container.
   * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the canvas.
   * @return {RenderingContext} The 2D canvas context.
   */
  function makeCanvas(id) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    container.innerHTML = '';
    canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;
    container.appendChild(canvas);

    return ctx;
  }


  /**
   * Create a visual legend inside the specified element based off of a
   * Chart.js dataset.
   * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the legend.
   * @param {Array.<Object>} items A list of labels and colors for the legend.
   */
  function generateLegend(id, items) {
    var legend = document.getElementById(id);
    legend.innerHTML = items.map(function(item) {
      var color = item.color || item.fillColor;
      var label = item.label;
      return '<li><i style="background:' + color + '"></i>' +
          escapeHtml(label) + '</li>';
    }).join('');
  }


  // Set some global Chart.js defaults.
  Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
  Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = 'easeInOutQuart';
  Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
  Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;


  /**
   * Escapes a potentially unsafe HTML string.
   * @param {string} str An string that may contain HTML entities.
   * @return {string} The HTML-escaped string.
   */
  function escapeHtml(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    return div.innerHTML;
  }

});
JS;
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);

?>
<div class="embedheader">
  <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
  <div id="view-selector-container"></div>
  <div id="view-name"></div>
  <div id="active-users-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>This Week vs Last Week (by sessions)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-1-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-1-container"></ol>
</div>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>This Year vs Last Year (by users)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-2-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-2-container"></ol>
</div>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>Top Browsers (by pageview)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-3-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-3-container"></ol>
</div>
<div class="Chartjs">
  <h3>Top Countries (by sessions)</h3>
  <figure class="Chartjs-figure" id="chart-4-container"></figure>
  <ol class="Chartjs-legend" id="legend-4-container"></ol>
</div>
```